# How to get ultra wide camera calibration data?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Is it possible to get calibration data `AVCapturePhoto::cameraCalibrationData` for ultra wide camera?

Documentation says:

> Camera calibration data is present only if you specified the cameraCalibrationDataDeliveryEnabled and dualCameraDualPhotoDeliveryEnabled settings when requesting capture.

but `dualCameraDualPhotoDeliveryEnabled` was deprecated.

I tried to set `cameraCalibrationDataDeliveryEnabled` for `builtInDualWideCamera` and `builtInUltraWideCamera` without any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calibration data is meant to give you information about the intrinsics of multiple cameras in a virtual camera capture scenario. This used to be the dual camera (introduced with the iPhone X), but with the release of the iPhone 11 Pro, the API switched it's naming. It's now called `isVirtualDeviceConstituentPhotoDeliveryEnabled` and you can now specify the set of cameras that should be involved in the capture with `virtualDeviceConstituentPhotoDeliveryEnabledDevices`.

Note that the calibration data only seem to be available for virtual devices with at least two cameras involved (so `builtInDualCamera`, `builtInDualWideCamera` and `builtInTripleCamera`).

Furthermore, if using a virtual device which includes the ultra wide camera (only have tested with `builtInDualWideCamera`), you need to disable geometric distortion via `captureDevice.isGeometricDistortionCorrectionEnabled=false` to disable the distortion correction on the ultra wide in order to enable camera calibration data delivery.